# Camel: how to predict HTTP charchester encoding when doing conversion

Tags: http, apache-camel

Doing this way:

```
from("direct:foo").
to("http://foo.com/bar.html").
convertBodyTo(String.class, "cp1251").
to("file:///tmp/bar.html")
```

However some pages I crawl could have encoding different from cp1251. How to determine encoding (either using `Content-Type` HTTP header or meta/@http-equiv' charset) and call `convertBodyTo()` using appropriate charset? May be `Camel HTTP` component could do that? What's `Exchange.HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add processor to set the exchange property with the header Exchange.CHARSET_NAME, the value could be information you get from the Http header content-type.
At this point, camel can know the encoding it can use.

Comment: I can't know `Content-type; charset` until I download the page. I can't set Exchange.CHARSET_NAME before that.

Comment: I already committed a patch to camel master branch, please check out latest camel 2.13-SNAPSHOT for verification.

Comment: Ok. I've upgraded to camel-2.13.0. How to use that feature? Should I `setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING, constant('UTF-8'))`? Tried w/ and w/o that option - no success. I'm still getting resulted windows-1251 unreadable (not UTF-8).

Comment: No, you don't need to use the setHeader and convertBodyTo with latest camel.

Comment: Tried w/ and w/o that option - no success. I'm still getting resulted windows-1251 unreadable. I'll update my post now with recent code.

Comment: You can submit a test case to the JIRA CAMEL-7217, I can take a look at it. BTW, you need to check the result of http://foo.com/bar.html, which encoding is changed according the content-type header.

Comment: Have attached patch to CAMEL-7217

Comment: I just added a comment to CAMEL-7217.